# Dealing with PHP scripts in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a basic question to you. I'm creating several js scripts, like this:

```
<script>
$('#mapveto1').click(function() {
    $('#mapveto1').addClass('banned');
    $('#map1').text('cobblestone has been banned');
    <? $remaining = $remaining -1; ?>
    $('#banstatus').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat glyphicon-repeat-animate"></span> Maps are being banned <? echo $remaining; ?>');

});
</script>
```

In every script, the id of element is being changed. As you can see, there are some PHP variables in it.

The thing is, these php lines are being executed always, even when I don't run this script by clicking on the element.
How can I make php scripts which will be executed ONLY when a js script is?

Comment: php runs on server long before javascript runs in the page

Comment: Don't mix up PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: this example below to the way to pass variable in a sample way, but be ware about what `$remaining` variable output finally before passing it to Javascript using this way.

another way to do the task with [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request witch recommended to POST & GET data.

If you need to pass PHP variable to JavaScript global variable you can do like

```
var js_variable = <?php echo $php_variable; ?>;//copy from php to js
```

then use `js_variable++` or `js_variable--` with your click event or use `js_variable` wherever.

So your Example will be

```
<script>
var remaining = <? echo $remaining; ?>
$('#mapveto1').click(function() {
    $('#mapveto1').addClass('banned');
    $('#map1').text('cobblestone has been banned');
    remaining--;
   //or remaining -= 1;
   //or remaining = remaining -1;    
$('#banstatus').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat glyphicon-repeat-animate"></span> Maps are being banned '+ remaining);

});
</script>
```

Comment: This is such a horrible way to code such things. Way better to have PHP run on the server, and rethink how this is done, or at least fetch the information via a call to ajax. Mixing javascript and PHP directly is just a first stepping stone to horrible security issues and parse errors waiting to happen.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie It doesn't have to be.  Sure, the way this is done is nightmarish, but it's entirely possible to generate JavaScript with PHP, and can be useful in some circumstances.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer At least use `json_encode()` to get that data safe for use in JavaScript... but note that this doesn't totally save you since you have JavaScript also in the context of HTML.

Comment: I think there is no security issues in this example no data sent or received, that i thought.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer Security or not, we have no idea what `$remaining` is (and even if we have a hunch today, we don't know what it will be tomorrow).  Any time you use data in a different context, you need to escape it for that context.  Always.

Comment: @Brad yes you are right but i put the way. sure he should handled $remaining to output a number as i understood in his php script.

Comment: @brad granted, creating javascript with PHP is fine in the right circumstances, but this is not that.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Agreed completely!

Comment: Exaggerated with this sample example, $remraning is not my.